# Java add a jpanel in a jtabbed pane in a jframe from another class file

Tags: java, swing

I am lost, can you please help?

I am trying to add a `jPanel` from a another class into a different file into a `JTabbedPane` in `JFrame` file.

Here is what I have so far.

```
jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
```

Answer (score 1):

One party needs a reference to the other in some way, for example, in your "other" class, you could provide a getter method...

```
public class OtherClass ... {
    public JPanel getComponent() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Then in your main UI, you could use the instance of `OtherClass` to get a reference to the `JPanel`...

```
tabbedPane.addTab("My Awesome Tab", instanceOfOtherClass.getComponent());
```

But this is all hypernethtical and is just one possible solution...